# Drag down to change row letter, not number

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry for the confusing title, but I don't know how else to explain this. I'm trying to drag down this cell with the following formula:

```
=COUNT(Tab1!B3:B32,"<>0")
```

What I want is for the letters to go down from A-Z (or B-Z, in this case) to get this eventually:

```
=COUNT(Tab1!Z3:Z32,"<>0")
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` function to shift the range to be referenced.

```
=COUNT(OFFSET(Tab1!$B$3:$B$32,0, ROW()-N,"<>0")
```

Where `OFFSET(Tab1!$B$3:$B$32,0,1) returns Tab1!$C$3:$C$32`.  Making the last parameter relative to the row number then you can drag down the cell (You should replace N with the row number of the first cell).